# Is Context.Items user scope or application scope?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

I want to use Context.Items to store some info of a User Control like:

```
Context.Items["Data"] = 5;
```

I want to know, Is Context.Items is for each request or it is global for the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpContext is per request.